# Zapier - Python IF/ELIF not printing result, "output_missing: Please define output or return early."

Tags: python, if-statement, zapier

I'm incredibly weak with Python, but I thought I could knock together a basic script to alert me when a new user adds a card, and compare their credentials against the account sign-up information (to check for spammers).

Here's what I have in Zapier:

```
if input_data['card_name'] == input_data['account_name'] and input_data['card_country'] == input_data['account_country'] and input_data['card_type'] != 'prepaid':
    print "Low Risk (valid credentials)"    
elif input_data['card_name'] == input_data['account_name'] and input_data['card_country'] == input_data['account_country'] and input_data['card_type'] == 'prepaid':
    print "Medium Risk (prepaid card)"    
elif input_data['card_name'] != input_data['account_name'] and input_data['card_country'] == input_data['account_country'] and input_data['card_type'] != 'prepaid':
    print "Medium Risk (name mismatch)"    
elif input_data['card_name'] == input_data['account_name'] and input_data['card_country'] != input_data['account_country'] and input_data['card_type'] != 'prepaid':
    print "Medium Risk (country mismatch)"    
elif input_data['card_name'] != input_data['account_name'] and input_data['card_country'] != input_data['account_country'] and input_data['card_type'] == 'prepaid':
    print "High Risk (consider investigating)"
```

It's a bunch of `if` / `elif`, but for some reason it's not printing the output. I had it working when it was only two conditions per argument, but with three it seems to not want to print the output.

I'm getting this error now:

> output_missing: Please define output or return early.

Am I making any mistakes that's preventing this from printing properly?

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

You're seeing this error because you're returning anything from the function (and the default `output` variable that's returned if nothing else is is `None`).

There's documentation about this [here](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#data-variables). If you `return {'a': 1}` at the end of your if statements you'll see the print output as a result of the zap. Or, instead of printing you could `return {'message': 'Low Risk (valid credentials)'}`, which will also show up as a result.

Either works, just depends what you need to do with the results.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!